# Conditional indexing not working in ingest node pipelines

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Am trying to implement an index template with datastream enabled and then set contains in ingest node pipelines. So that I could get metrics with below-mentioned index format :

.ds-metrics-kubernetesnamespace

I had tried this sometime back and I did these things as mentioned above and it was giving metrics in such format but now when I implement the same it's not changing anything in my index. I cannot see any logs in openshift cluster so ingest seems to be working fine(when I add a doc and test it works fine)

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/metrics-index
{
   "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
      "field": "_index",
      "value": "metrics-{{kubernetes.namespace}}",
      "if": "ctx.kubernetes?.namespace==\"dev\""
       }
    }
   ]
}
```

This is the ingest node condition I have used for indexing.

```
    metricbeatConfig:
      metricbeat.yml: |
        metricbeat.modules:
        - module: kubernetes
          enabled: true
          metricsets:
            - state_node
            - state_daemonset
            - state_deployment
            - state_replicaset
            - state_statefulset
            - state_pod
            - state_container
            - state_job
            - state_cronjob
            - state_resourcequota
            - state_service
            - state_persistentvolume
            - state_persistentvolumeclaim
            - state_storageclass
            - event
```

Comment: How do you tell your documents to go through the `metrics-index` ingest pipeline?

Comment: i have specified that in metricbeat.yml file which is deployed on openshift

Comment: Is this the only processor you have in your pipeline?

Comment: yes. I was checking if it works but it's not changing the index am not understanding what is going on as it does not throw any error in openshift or in ingest pipeline UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Metricbeat, you have another way to do this which is much better.

Simply configure your `elasticsearch` output like this:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://<host>:<port>"]
  indices:
    - index: "%{[kubernetes.namespace]}"
      mappings:
        dev: "metrics-dev"
      default: "metrics-default"
```

or like this:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://<host>:<port>"]
  indices:
    - index: "metrics-%{[kubernetes.namespace]}"
      when.equals:
        kubernetes.namespace: "dev"
      default: "metrics-default"
```

or simply like this would also work if you have plenty of different namespaces and you don't want to manage different mappings:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://<host>:<port>"]
  index: "metrics-%{[kubernetes.namespace]}"
```

Comment: We have like 30-40 namespace so doing on the yml will not look good. Ideally, it must happen in ingest pipelines like logstash/ingest node and I feel that is a better practice. Hence, I did not implement this. What is the better way of doing this ? I am wrong here

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: I am afraid this also does not work. It was working sometime back in the early December . Now ingest as well as conditions in yml does not work. Is there something that is causing the elastic running index to have more priority than the conditions that I set ?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information regarding your Metricbeat configuration. Are there enabled modules (if yes, which ones)? Which version are you running (Both ES and MB)? What was different earl December that changed in the meantime?

Comment: Metricbeat has Kubernetes and Prometheus modules but no significant changes from what was present in December

Comment: Which version? Can you share the respective module configurations? What did change since early December when it worked and doesn't anymore, what did you do exactly? The more info you provide, the better. Help us help you!

Comment: added the Kubernetes module I can't see any version in that. I had added an index template nothing in metricbeat.yml has changed I had made an index template and deleted it that is what I remember

Comment: Hey, i figured out by checking logs in my deployment metricbeat it was telling it did not have enough permission to create index I have fixed this now. So with ingest am getting the index in metrics-dev pattern now need to get in form of data streams

Comment: Awesome, just a permission issue... However, you really don't need an ingest pipeline just for that (+ you have configuration in two different places... error prone). In your template definition, you simply need to add `data_stream:{}` and you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Steps to create datastreams in elastic stack:

1. create an ILM policy
2. Create an index template that has an index pattern that matches with the index pattern of metrics/logs.(Set number of primary shards/replica shards and mapping in index template)
3. Set a condition in ingest pipeline.(Make sure no such index exist)

If these conditions meet it will create a data stream and logs/metrics would have an index starting with .ds- and it will be hidden in index management.

In my case the issue was I did not have enough permission to create a custom index. When I checked my OpenShift logs I could find metricbeat was complaining about the privilege. So I gave Superuser permission and then used ingest node to set conditional indexing

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/metrics-index
{
   "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
      "field": "_index",
      "value": "metrics-{{kubernetes.namespace}}",
      "if": "ctx.kubernetes?.namespace==\"dev\""
       }
    }
   ]
}
```

Comment: This answer solve my problem :)